# Should one accept a full time job where the contract says "part time"?

Tags: contracts, retail

My brother has been working part time in UK. He was offered a job in a shop: "you will do 30 hours per week, but the contract will just state a minimum of 16 hours per week".
Is this common practice in UK? I understand that this offers much more flexibility to the employer and potentially screws the employee. Do you have any experience about such a job offer? To me this sounds bad, but it would be a step up...

Comment: Deliberately wrong contract content? Sounds as much illegal as it can get, so "No, don´t accept it"

Comment: I would look up what qualifies as full time employment.  In the US there are certain rules and regulations that apply to full time and not part time with that being determined by how many hours per week.  I would be very careful with this and consult a lawyer (or relevant government agency) if you have additional questions.

Comment: Not an expert on UK tax/insurance law, but this seems like they're trying to dodge some regulatory requirement.

Comment: If he's supposed to work 30 hours per week, then the contract must stipulate that, as well as the remuneration and any benefits or conditions.  Are they going to _pay_ him for 16 hours a week?  Sounds very... odd.

Comment: Could this be a contract minimum of 16 hours a week, but up to 30 hours if there is enough work for it?

Comment: In the news in the UK of late: [Zero hours contracts](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-23573442). As @BjarkeFreund-Hansen suggests, this sounds like a similar practice - a certain number of contracted hours, plus routine overtime.

Comment: What would you say if they had said "In the contract we'll put a salary of X pounds per month, but in reality we will only pay you half of that."? That's basically what that contract sounds like to me.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: Bjarke got it right.

Comment: @StackTA42 That is definitely critical information which completely changes the situation. I've updated your question to clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fairly routine in the UK, especially in retail.  It's like the infamous "Zero hours contract" you see in the news, but slightly better.

In a zero hours scenario you work a certain number of paid hours per week, but they don't promise you will get that every week (although you may).  This is easier than paying people off when demand dips, you just reduce their hours (possibly to zero), and when demand picks up you give out more hours to your pool.  The government is changing the rules so if you work a certain number of hours every week for a certain number of weeks that will become your minimum, rather than zero.  To which employers will just keep varying your hours to avoid it being fixed.

In your case they are promising at least 16 hours a week, but at the moment they need your brother for 30, for which he will get paid.  However if demand drops, he'll still get at least 16 hours a week.

Where this has more of an effect is in loans/mortgages etc, where they will usually (but not always) calculate earnings on contracted (i.e. 16) hours.

So not dodgy, but I'd base any budgeting on the 16 hours, even if I was getting a regular 30, and the rest is bonus/savings etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Should one accept a full time job where the contract says “part time”?
>
> "you will do 30 hours per week, but the contract will just state a
>   minimum of 16 hours per week"

One should accept a job based pretty much exclusively on what the written contract says.

Thus, you should expect that this is actually a 16-hour-per-week job. For me, that isn't the same as "full time".

Verbal promises outside of a contract have a way of not being fulfilled, and often cannot be enforced. Conditions change, more people get hired, there are fewer hours to spread around, the person originally making the promise leaves, etc, etc.

You can rely far more on what is written in the contract than what anyone says.

If you really wanted a full time job, I wouldn't accept this contract. You will get 16 hours. You might get 30 hours, or you might not. Your mileage may vary.